# Why do Unit Testing Attributes usually require public Methods?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I recently noted that adding [TestInitialize] to a protected method in a .NET assembly wasn't respected, but if I made the method public it was called by the unit test runner (Resharper in this case). I've noticed this several times in the past with test methods.

Technically speaking, its just as easy to reflect on a private method as a public method. As a matter of fact, reflection is a method employed to unit test private methods.

So why do I need to make all my unit test methods public?

Comment: That's a really good question.  The only good argument I've heard is that it follows the principle "program to an interface, not to an implementation,"   part of the SOLID principles.

Comment: I don't think he's talking about testing his classes, he's talking about the actual test methods that are called by test framework.

Comment: @JustinDearing: Are you talking about making the test methods public, or making the methods under test public?  Making test methods public is not controversial; it's easier for the Test Runner to run them that way.  Put your test methods in another assembly if you don't want them to be part of the assembly under test's public API.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in Java, reason for similar restriction (eg in JUnit) is that framework designers don't want to mess with [`setAccessible` which can be blocked by some custom SecurityManager](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2489644/839601)

Comment: ...hey, in .Net invoking [members that are inaccessible according to the accessibility rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also involves messing with security / permissions. If I was a framework designer, I'd guess that my future users would be _less unhappy_ to live with requirement of public methods than with one to take care of permissions

Comment: @gnat Well ok I could see a use case for a unit test running being launched in a locked down appdomain. Then again, that would be a problem if I was unit testing code that used reflection.

Comment: you need to take in account that this design decision was made for a general purpose framework targeted for wide usage. In cases like that it's just safer for designer to assume and prepare to the worst. If it was, I don't know, some company-internal framework (where one can have chance to guarantee desired security policies), or if it was some tool of narrow, specialized purpose (think "viewer for inaccessible members"), designer would have other options to consider

Comment: I don't think it is any more difficult to access private members via reflection, which is used anyway to look up the test classes and members. Perhaps it is a historical restriction based on past problems.

Comment: @FrankHileman if it's modern to spare developers from any means of restricting reflection to access code that is not intended to be accessible, it would be probably safer to stay in the past

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only Microsoft can answer this question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt This behavior is found in Nunit, and probably other test frameworks Microsoft didn't write. Sure in the years since asking this question I understand a lot more about .NET, but I still think its a fair question, and there is some good discussion in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You should Test what the class *does*, not *how* it does it.

As far as the "Outside World" is concerned, that's whatever the class makes Publically available; your Testing framework is making the same assumption.

By testing anything "less" than Public, you're delving into the class' internal implementation, which is a Bad Idea.

Comment: Note that the question is about the test methods, and not the methods in the system under test. While it is true that OP argues that you can use reflection to test things "less" than public, it is an argument about the ability of test frameworks to access private methods. The test framework has to use reflection to find the test methods (that are marked by an attribute), and thus must use reflection, with that in mind... "why do I need to make all my unit test methods public?"

Comment: Test methods have the ability to access private methods; with Reflection, anything is possible.  I see this question more about the [un]desirability of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it's best to only access public methods - when you create a class, you're also creating the contract as to which other classes should access your code. So the answer is most likely just because it's a convention.

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question.